# Does rotating text get picked up for SEO?

Tags: html, seo

Does rotating text like on apple.com's homepage get picked up in spiders for search engines? Is rotating text relavent in SEO?

Comment: What rotating text are you referring to, specifically?

Comment: Yeah, what kind of rotating text? In a movie? In a jQuery animation?

Answer (score 2):

If depends on how you're rotating your text.  Generally speaking, search engines don't pick up content that has a property of `display: none` (in a good way); also, if you're using JavaScript to add the content to the page, this will also not get picked up.

If the content is visible, just maybe off-screen or behind a layer(s) it will get picked up, and not be viewed as "bad" content.

In terms of relevancy, yes it's relevant.

You can read more about hidden text, etc.. here:  http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66353

Comment: "Generally speaking, search engines don't pick up content that has a property of display: none"  - Do you have a source for this? The page you linked says nothing about this.

Comment: I said in a "in a good way" - From the link:  "Hiding text or links in your content can cause your site to be perceived as untrustworthy since it presents information to search engines differently than to visitors."

Comment: "if you're using JavaScript to add the content to the page, this will also not get picked up" can't find it now, but Google mentioned they acually are constantly improving indexing JS generated content now.

Answer (score 1):

If the internal markup of any website is schematically produced, no matter what advanced animation techniques are added, the website will make sense to search engines.

However, if the animation generates the text on-the-fly or is loaded in not as a part of the internal markup, search engines may not be able to see it.